ggplotly: add "gravity" to stacked bar charts, so deselecting middle categories will make top categories slide down
I am trying to make a stacked bar chart where 1) the user can select what categories to see AND 2) when the user deselects a category, the remaining categories "align up so they continous".
Objective 1 is accomplished with this code:
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  area = rep(c('EU', 'USA'), each = 3),
  category = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
  value = c('35', '45', '20', '25', '45', '30')
)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(fill = category, y = value, x = area)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
p <- ggplotly(p)
p

But now if the user deselect category A, category C will be hovering above B:

What I want is something that "adds gravity" to the stacked bar chart, so that removing categories in the middle of other categories, will make the top categories slide down, i.e., after deselecting category A, the plot looks like this instead:
data <- data.frame(
  area = rep(c('EU', 'USA'), each = 2),
  category = c('B', 'C', 'B', 'C'),
  value = c('45', '20', '45', '30')
)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(fill = category, y = value, x = area)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
p <- ggplotly(p)
p


I suppose this could be make in shiny but 1) I need to distribute the rapport pr email, 2) I dont know any shiny currently, so an easier solution would be much appreciated.

I'm hopeful there's a more modern solution, but potential duplicate: Bar chart in plotly flies when deselecting variables

Your second stacked bar chart looks wrong because your y-axis variable, value, is of type character, not numeric. Use as.numeric() to convert the text strings into numbers and make it work as intended.
